# redirect default website - iis 7, MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to redirect default website(iis) https://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com/xyz using URL rewrite module and HTTP redirect, but it's not working.

My application is deployed at https://www.domain.com/xyz.

Application Type: ASP.NET MVC 5

Authentication: Windows

IIS Version: 7.5

Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect all the calls coming to default website on your web site you can use HTTP Redirect option .

Steps 1

Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI based on your IIS administrative role, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).

Step 2

In Features View, double-click HTTP Redirect.
[image]

step 3
On the HTTP Redirect page, select Redirect requests to this destination. In the corresponding box, type the file name, directory path, or URL to which you want to redirect the user.

[image]

Step 4

In the Actions pane, click Apply.

Ref :- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930(v=ws.10).aspx

let me know how it worked for you.

Comment: I have tried this solution before, it didn't work. I am redirecting to MVC app.

Comment: can you tell me what was the url?

Comment: destination url - /xyz/home/index (app/controller/view)

Comment: I am not getting what you want to do .you want to redirect lets say from yahoo.com to google.com or you want to go from yahoo.com to yahoo.com/Users/Profile

Comment: My default site url  is - www.domain.com and MY application url is - www.domain.com/xyz (an mvc application). I want to redirect default site to my application.

Comment: It works now! I have to clear browser cache and cookies.

Comment: Great. Congratulations.

Comment: @user2698332 : If this answer works for you can you please accept it and i will really appreciate if you can up vote it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, in addition to your solution. I would like to add a point, httpredirect on default site will  be applicable to all the applications under it. We need to **disable** httpredirect for each application under default site.